# Tensor product notation for Cartesian product

Tags: soft-question, notation

I have recently seen a lot of papers using $\bigotimes_{j=1}^n A_j$ to denote the Cartesian product of sets, without mentioning they do so.

Just out of curiosity, is this notation standard in some communities or countries?

Comment: Could you provide some examples of such papers?

Comment: @Tobias "Analytic regularity and polynomial approximation of parametric and stochastic elliptic PDEs" (2011) Cohen, Devore, Schwab. In: Anaysis and Applications. (Eqn. 1.24)

Comment: That's weird...that paper even appears to refer to a Cartesian product as "the tensor product" on page 18.

Comment: @Eric Right? And this wording is used in other papers as well (from the same and from different authors)! But the authors above are all highly reputated, so I'd assume they know what they're talking about